# Codeigniter - Form validation runs, but won't display errors on FALSE

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I'm running into a situation with Form Validation. For something so easy, I can't seem to figure out where my issue is, and I have searched online for quite awhile. My form, when left blank, should throw errors via `form_error` for each field if `form_validation` returns FALSE. However, nothing happens. When the form is filled out completely, it inserts to the DB just fine. I'm stuck and I can't seem to figure out what the solution is. My thoughts are that the code has a misspelling in it somewhere or the form isn't designed correctly.

Here is my Controller:

```
function create_job()
    {
        // validate each form field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('repair_order', 'Repair Order', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('vin', 'VIN', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'Vehicle Year', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('make', 'Vehicle Make', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('model', 'Vehicle Model', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('start_date', 'Start Date', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('promise_date', 'Promise Date', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('body_hours', 'Body Labor Hours', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('paint_hours', 'Paint Labor Hours', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('body_tech', 'Body Technician', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('paint_tech', 'Paint Technician', 'required');

            if($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                $data = array(
                'repair_order'      => $this->input->post('repair_order'),
                'first_name'        => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name'         => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'address'           => $this->input->post('address'),
                'city'              => $this->input->post('city'),
                'state'             => $this->input->post('state'),
                'zip_code'          => $this->input->post('zip_code'),
                'phone'             => $this->input->post('phone'),
                'vin'               => $this->input->post('vin'),
                'year'              => $this->input->post('year'),
                'make'              => $this->input->post('make'),
                'model'             => $this->input->post('model'),
                'start_date'        => $this->input->post('start_date'),
                'promise_date'      => $this->input->post('promise_date'),
                'body_hours'        => $this->input->post('body_hours'),
                'paint_hours'       => $this->input->post('paint_hours'),
                'insurance'         => $this->input->post('insurance'),
                'body_tech'         => $this->input->post('body_tech'),
                'paint_tech'        => $this->input->post('paint_tech')
                );
                $this->db->insert('jobs', $data);

                $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "New job has been successfully created.");
                redirect('main');
            }
            else
            {
                redirect('jobs/new');
            }
    }
```

And here is my form:

```
<div class="my-3 my-md-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
          <h3 class="card-title">New Job</h3>
          </div>
            <div class="card-body">
               <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jobs/create" method="post"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label">Repair Order/Job Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="repair_order" placeholder="Enter Job Name or Number" value="<?php echo set_value('repair_order'); ?>">
                  <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('repair_order'); ?></small></span>
                </div>
                <h3>Customer Information</h3>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('first_name'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo set_value('last_name'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('last_name'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Home Address" value="<?php echo set_value('address'); ?>">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label">City</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="City" value="<?php echo set_value('city'); ?>">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label class="form-label">State</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="state">
                      <option value="<?php echo set_value('state'); ?>"><?php echo set_value('state'); ?></option>
                      <option value="">Ohio</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <label class="form-label">Zip Code</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip_code" placeholder="Zip Code" value="<?php echo set_value('zip_code'); ?>">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <label class="form-label">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="<?php echo set_value('phone'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('phone'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <h3>Vehicle Information</h3>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-9">
                    <label class="form-label">VIN</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vin" placeholder="VIN" value="<?php echo set_value('vin'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('vin'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <label class="form-label">Vehicle Year</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="year" placeholder="Year" value="<?php echo set_value('year'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('year'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label">Vehicle Make</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="make" placeholder="Make" value="<?php echo set_value('make'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('make'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label">Vehicle Model</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="model" placeholder="Model" value="<?php echo set_value('model'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('model'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <h3>Workflow Information</h3> 
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label">Start Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date" value="<?php echo set_value('start_date'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('start_date'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label">Promise Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="promise_date" value="<?php echo set_value('promise_date'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('promise_date'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <label class="form-label">Total Body Labor Hours</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="body_hours" placeholder="Body Labor" value="<?php echo set_value('body_hours'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('body_hours'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <label class="form-label">Total Paint Labor Hours</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="paint_hours" placeholder="Paint Labor" value="<?php echo set_value('paint_hours'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('paint_hours'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label">Insurance Company</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="insurance" placeholder="Insurance Company" value="<?php echo set_value('insurance'); ?>">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label">Body Technician</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="body_tech">
                      <option value="<?php echo set_value('body_tech'); ?>"><?php echo set_value('body_tech'); ?></option>
                      <option value="Roy Whittenberger">Roy Whittenberger</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('body_tech'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label">Paint Technician</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="paint_tech">
                      <option value="<?php echo set_value('paint_tech'); ?>"><?php echo set_value('paint_tech'); ?></option>
                      <option value="Joel Lakosh">Joel Lakosh</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="text-danger"><small><?php echo form_error('paint_tech'); ?></small></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-footer">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </form>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm a novice with CodeIgniter, just trying to learn. If anyone can see where the issue lays and can guide me to an answer, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Does the redirect to main work if the form is successful?

Comment: Yes, the argument for TRUE works, ONLY IF the form is filled out completely. If the form is not filled out entirely, it returns FALSE, but does not show the error messages.

Comment: Additionally, everything that is required is already set in autoload. I also have multiple forms in my project already that have no issues. This one, in particular, just doesn't want to work correctly.

Comment: Instead of redirect('jobs/new'); use $this->load->view('jobs/new') - or whatever the view is for your form

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you! Funny how something as simple as ```redirect``` versus ```view``` can change things. If you would like, submit as an answer and I will upvote you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect won't pass on the form_error messages. You need to load a view (your form) in order to call form_error using `$this->load->view()`

Try this:

```
function create_job()
{
    // validate each form field
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('repair_order', 'Repair Order', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('vin', 'VIN', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'Vehicle Year', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('make', 'Vehicle Make', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('model', 'Vehicle Model', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('start_date', 'Start Date', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('promise_date', 'Promise Date', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body_hours', 'Body Labor Hours', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('paint_hours', 'Paint Labor Hours', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body_tech', 'Body Technician', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('paint_tech', 'Paint Technician', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $data = array(
            'repair_order'      => $this->input->post('repair_order'),
            'first_name'        => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name'         => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'address'           => $this->input->post('address'),
            'city'              => $this->input->post('city'),
            'state'             => $this->input->post('state'),
            'zip_code'          => $this->input->post('zip_code'),
            'phone'             => $this->input->post('phone'),
            'vin'               => $this->input->post('vin'),
            'year'              => $this->input->post('year'),
            'make'              => $this->input->post('make'),
            'model'             => $this->input->post('model'),
            'start_date'        => $this->input->post('start_date'),
            'promise_date'      => $this->input->post('promise_date'),
            'body_hours'        => $this->input->post('body_hours'),
            'paint_hours'       => $this->input->post('paint_hours'),
            'insurance'         => $this->input->post('insurance'),
            'body_tech'         => $this->input->post('body_tech'),
            'paint_tech'        => $this->input->post('paint_tech')
            );
            $this->db->insert('jobs', $data);

            $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "New job has been successfully created.");
            redirect('main');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('yournewjobform');
        }
}
```